# BIDS 2005 RDL - Cannot specify two decimals on calculated field

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdlc

I am using VS 2005 to create a RDL. I would be using 2008 but it's not compatible unfortunately where we have a nice GUI to specify how many decimals.

Is there a way I can do this in the expression? Even in the textbox format properties I set it to currency `($1,234.12)` but on the report i'm getting for example $234.7864. How do can I specify only two decimals in VS 2005? The format code is "C" can i add `#.##` to it or something?

The derived field is:

```
=IIF((Fields!cal_variance.Value)<=0,"$0","$"&(Fields!cal_variance.Value)*9 )
```

Comment: I was able to get the decimal formatting corrected but now I lost my "$"                   =FormatNumber(IIF((Fields!cal_variance.Value)<=0,"$0","$"&(Fields!cal_variance.Value)*9 ),2)

Answer (score 0):

Sovled with FormatCurrency - who would have thought?